# Javascript function Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-plugins

I'm working on a project that uses the plugin [Circliful](https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful). I import it correctly on my HTML, place the file on the correct path, etc.

On my js file, I call it on start

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#kcalCircle").circliful({
        animationStep: 5,
        foregroundBorderWidth: 5,
        foregroundColor: '#FABE0E',
        backgroundBorderWidth: 10,
        percent: 0
    });
}
```

And it works, it generates the Circle as I intend it to.

However, if I try to do the same function call, inside any other function, like this one:

```
$('#macrosKnownButton').click(function() {
    ...
    $("#kcalCircle").circliful({
            animationStep: 5,
            foregroundBorderWidth: 5,
            foregroundColor: '#FABE0E',
            backgroundBorderWidth: 10,
            percent: 10
    });
    ...
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).circliful is not a function
    success @ interactions.js:193
    i @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2
    fireWith @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2
    z @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4
    (anonymous function) @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4
```

Since the plugin works on another situation, I don't think it's something wrong with it. My guess is something is happening on the Javascript that I'm not aware of.

Any ideas on why this is happening? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you missing a closing parenthesis on your `.click`? Or do you get the error on click?

Comment: No, everything on the function happens correctly. This happens on all the functions inside my document.ready function, not just on this one :/

Comment: Sounds like `circliful` isn't included properly.. here's a codepen of it working http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKRgvA

Comment: @mfink it is imported correctly because it generates the circles in some situations. And in your example, nothing happens when I click on the div :/